# ¿Como Asignarle El Valor De Un File A Un FileOutputStream?

Tags: android

Quiero asignarle el valor de carga de un file a un fileoutputstream porque el método que uso me obliga a solo usar fileoutputstream. El valor de carga del file es una ruta de un directorio donde se encuentra un archivo zip. Si saben como lograrlo se los agradeceré.

Comment: Estaría bien si mostraras tu código para ver hasta donde has llegado y que formularas mejor la  pregunta. Quieres de un file con un outputstream volcarlo dentro de un fichero que está en un .zip?

Comment: Es que en realidad no tengo idea de como lograr lo dicho.

Comment: Volcarlo dentro de un .zip no vas a poder... tendrás que descomprimirlo volvar tu archivo y volver a comprimirlo, dime si es eso lo que buscar y te hago una respuesta

Comment: Okey no puedo con un zip pero con una imagen si

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo

Comment: en un rato te preparo un fragmento de código para que veas cómo funciona

Comment: ok muchas gracias amigo.